# Empty String Validation Exception - DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have scoured the internet on how to fix this with little success...

I am parsing a CSV and putting the data into a table using DynamoDB.
Anytime there is a blank entry, I receive the error:

```
One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string
```

For example:

```
Header: "Name","Age","Birth date"
Entry:  Brandon,22  <------ THROWS ERROR
```

The problem is, I will never know if there are blanks or not in the CSV. But I still need to parse it even if there is.

I have attempted to re-assign the value of the empty string to something like "N/A" in an effort to subvert this error to no avail. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Code to add context.

```
var file = process.argv[2];
console.log("File: " + file);

var csv = require("fast-csv");

csv.fromPath(file, {
        headers: true,
        ignoreEmpty: true
    })
    .on("data", function(data) {
        // Uncomment to see CSV data
        // console.log(data);

        params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Item: {
                RefID: {
                    S: data["Ref-ID"]
                },
                //lots more items
            }
        };

        //Validation loops to make sure the items are defined
        for (var key in params.Item) {
            for (var items in params.Item[key]) {
                var value = params.Item[key][items];
                if (value === undefined || value === "") {
                    value = "N/A";
            }
        }

        dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, info) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
            else {
                console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
        // }

    })
    .on("end", function() {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

Comment: `I have attempted to re-assign the value of the empty string to something like "N/A" in an effort to subvert this error to no avail. ` Perhaps you need to show your code then, because that should work fine. Also you could just remove the attribute entirely from the Put command if the string is null.

Comment: I will add the code in an edit. Admittedly, the questions are similar, but I had many different problems that I solved through the last question. The problem is my main question of how to get around this specific error was never answered. I felt this post is more concise and much clearer than my last one (which had many issues).

Comment: You need to show more of your code. What are you doing with `value` after you assign something to it? It looks like you are just looping through the values, assigning each one to `value` and then throwing it away...

Comment: Also this literally looks like the same question you were asking previously, it is a question about how to handle the same error message. You shouldn't have marked that last question as answered if you didn't truly have an answer yet.

Comment: Done.

I was under the impression you would give someone the check mark if they helped you solve your problem or gave you the best answer. Although my problem wasn't entirely solved, he helped me solve other issues in my code and gave me a better understanding of what was going on. If I am wrong though, I won't let it happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere in your code are you assigning the values of name, age, etc. into your params object. Are you still not showing all the code? Disregarding that for a minute and looking at your validation loop, you are just throwing away the "N/A" value. You need to modify the actual `params` object you are using to insert records. Change the validation loop to this:

```
    //Validation loops to make sure the items are defined
    for (var key in params.Item) {
        for (var items in params.Item[key]) {
            var value = params.Item[key][items];
            if (value === undefined || value === "") {
                params.Item[key][items] = "N/A";
        }
    }
```

There's probably an easier way to do this as you are taking the values from `data` and copying that to the `params` object, but you don't seem to be showing that code.

Comment: OK, the error is gone, and the data is doing what I need it to. Thank you for your help, and I apologize if I misused this website. I will be more intentional next time in my ticks.

Answer (score 13):

Until now, lack of support for empty strings in DynamoDB's DocumentClient is still a limitation. However, you should know that since July 2017, AWS SDK [v2.7.16](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2716) added a constructor option (called `convertEmptyValues`) for [document client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) to convert empty strings, sets, and binary strings to a DynamoDB `NULL` typed field.

If this client-side workaround works out for you, you'll need to set to `true` if you would like the document client to convert empty values (0-length strings, binary buffers, and sets) to be converted to `NULL` types when persisting to DynamoDB.

Something like this:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    convertEmptyValues: true
});
```

Comment: As of June 2020, DynamoDB now supports empty string values for non-key attributes: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

Comment: @Aaron_H: If I read the announcement correctly, this only applies to Amazon DynamoDB local (i.e., the downloadable version of DynamoDB) and not DynamoDB web service.

Answer (score 1):

**2020 May 18 Update:**

DynamoDB now supports empty string values for non-key attributes: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

You should no longer see this Exception when writing to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

These functions work like a charm, just have to execute storageSerialize on your object before storing and storageDeserialize when you get an item.

You might want to get your object in the same state as in input.

Note: the code above is in Typescript, but you can easily adapt it

```
private storageSerialize(data: any) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
        let val = data[key];
        if (val == null) {
            data[key] = "PLACEHOLDER_NULL"
        }
        if (val == "") {
            data[key] = "PLACEHOLDER_EMPTYSTRING"
        }
    });
    return data;
}

private storageDeserialize(data: any) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
            let val = data[key];
            if (val == "PLACEHOLDER_NULL") {
                data[key] = null
            }
            if (val == "PLACEHOLDER_EMPTYSTRING") {
                data[key] = ""
            }
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can pass nullify_invalid new Marshaler(['nullify_invalid'=>true]);

Answer (score 0):

Adding this note as it may be helpful for others who use partiQL or use empty string in params.

The error still appears if you pass an empty param in where condition. For example , If you run below query in partiql ,you can see *"ValidationException: One or more key attribute values are not valid: The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value."*

```
SELECT  "mypartitionkey","my_sort_key","fullName" FROM "dynamodbtable"  WHERE "mypartitionkey"= 'profile' and my_sort_key in ('12345', '' )
```

but it will work if you pass run below

```
SELECT  "mypartitionkey","my_sort_key","fullName" FROM "dynamodbtable"  WHERE "mypartitionkey"= 'profile' and my_sort_key in ('12345' )
```